# Jump menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I am editing an existing site that has a link menu that loads content from a page into a DIV for some links, and goes to a different URL for others. Now the customer would like one of those links (eg: Page 2 which loads into the DIV) to be put onto the jump menu that displays for mobile.

The link menu and the jump menu work, but, the jump menu does not for the example of page2, we want to load content into a DIV, while keeping the other pages going to a URL.

The menus look like this:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="page1" id="1">Page One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="2">Page Two</a></li>
<li><a href="page3" id="3">Page Three</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<form name="mobilemenu" id="mobilemenu">
     <select id="mobile-jump-menu" name="mobile-jump-menu" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
<option value="Menu" selected="selected">Menu</option>
<option value="page1">Page One</option>
<option value="loadpage2">Page Two</option>
<option value="page3">Page Three</option>
</select>
</form>  

<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}

$("#2").click(function() {
        $("#content-box").load('content/page2');
        return false;
});


$(function() {
$('#mobile-jump-menu').change(function(){
if($('#mobile-jump-menu').val() == 'loadpage2') { 
    $("#content-box").load('content/page2');
}
});
});

-->
</script>
```

The Page2 in the jump menu does not work, I think because it is trying to run the two conflicting scripts....the content must be loaded into the DIV, so I need to find out how to do that for just the one link on the jump menu :(

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the function MM_jumpMenu and add an if condition inside it, haven't tested the code but should work.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0

 if(selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value =="loadpage2"){
     $("#content-box").load('content/page2');
 }else{
    eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
 }

if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}

$("#2").click(function() {
        $("#content-box").load('content/page2');
        return false;
});

-->
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!